# powershell: Remove a instance of a System.String?

Tags: string, variables, powershell

How do a remove a instance of a System.String variable?

$Servers = "server","localhost"

I want to remove localhost, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set to `$null` the Array entry (you must know the index):

```
$Servers.Set(1, $NULL)
```

If you need a return value of `[string]`  not an `[objtect[]]`

```
[string]$Servers = $Servers[0] # need always knowing the indexs
```

If the Array count > 2 you need to do:

```
$Servers = $servers | ? { $_ -ne "localhost" }
```

or in short way

```
$servers = $servers -ne "localhost"
```

Or you can cast to `ArrayList`:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$servers = $servers
$servers.Remove("localhost")
```

Comment: i chose to do it like below as it makes more sense to me.

$servers = $servers -ne "localhost"